# The whole App is lagging while loading pictures swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hello my App is lagging while i load pictures from a server.
I can't scroll or go to the next view controller without a massiv delay.
I tried to do it with `DispatchQueue.main.async`and `OperationQueue,main.addQueue`
In the DispatchQueue method I couldn't do anything only wait.
And on the left side I can see a bit of the last view controller.

Here is my Code

```
func fetchData(uiView: UIView) {

        let urlString = URL(string: "https://mydomain/assats/php/Random.php")!
         let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlString) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                debugPrint("Fehler beim Laden von \(urlString)", String(describing: error))
                return
            }
                   let JSONData = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Pics].self, from: data)
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                let currentWidthScroll: Int = (100 / 1) - (100 / 1) + (1 * 0) + (1 * 0) + 0
                        let currentHighScroll: Int = (100 / 1) - (100 / 1) + (1 * 100) + (1 * 5) + 21
                        let screensize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
                        let screenWidth = screensize.width
                        let screenHeight = screensize.height
                        var scrollView = UIScrollView()
                            scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(currentWidthScroll), y: CGFloat(currentHighScroll), width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
                             self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
                if JSONData == nil {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You can't see much here because you don't Follow anybody", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                }
                              
                else {
                    
                   for x in 0..<JSONData!.count {
                        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                            print(x)
                    
                            
                       let currentWidth: Int = (100 / 1) - (100 / 1) + (x * 0) + (x * 0) + 10
                                   
                         let currentHigh: Int = (100 / 1) - (100 / 1) + (x * 500) + (x * 5) + 80
                         let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(currentWidth), y: CGFloat(currentHigh), width: 350, height: 500))
                    
                                   
                         stackView.alignment = .fill
                         stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
                         stackView.axis = .vertical
                        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: currentHigh + 650)
                        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
                    
                    
                   let urlKey = "http://instapy.ddns.net/User/\(JSONData![x].Benutzername)/Posts/Photos/\(JSONData![x].Pic)"
                    let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(currentWidth), y: CGFloat(currentHigh), width: 350, height: 500))
                    imgView.image = UIImage(named: urlKey)
                    imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    stackView.addArrangedSubview(imgView)
                    
                       if let url = URL(string: urlKey) {
                           
                       do{
                            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                           imgView.image = UIImage(data: data)

                           }catch let err {
                           print("Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        };task.resume()
    }
```

I load the function in the viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here

```
 let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
```

the above line shouldn't be in main queue as it'll block it ,  i guess you need a tableView here instead of the scrollView + stackView and load the image with their urls preferably by [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

Comment: [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) works well too

Comment: No changed a bit of the Dispatch and now it work perfect. :)

Comment: Note using a background queue will solve it but it’s not the correct to headache your server with loading images that user may not scroll to see it